# Error on multiple upload in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make multiple file upload with Laravel 5.4.

At the moment I get this error, when submit:

> ErrorException in Factory.php line 91: Argument 2 passed to
>   Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null
>   given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs***\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest.php
>   on line 102 and defined

Form here:

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['posts.store'], 'files' => true,]) !!}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'Title*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::label('description', 'Description*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('description', null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::file('fotos[]', array('multiple'=>true), [ 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller (store):

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{


 $input = $request->all();

if($input->hasFile('fotos[]'))
{
    foreach ($request->file('fotos[]') as $file) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('/images/', $name);
        Foto::create(['post_id'=>$post->id, 'filename'=>$name]);

    }
}

$post->fotos()->create($input);

return redirect()->route('posts.index');
 }
```

Foto model:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post'); }
```

Post model:

```
public function fotos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Foto');}
```

PostRequest:

```
{public function rules()
[
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach should be

```
foreach(Input::file("myfile") as $file) {
    //process each file
}
```

[Check this Laracast Thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multiple-upload-with-laravel/replies/9537)

and hash should be

```
if (Input::hasFile(''))
{
    //
}
```

[Read more about this on Laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files)

Comment: For laravel 5.4 please have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files The Input facade isn't used anymore.